# Is there a coordinate system similar to polar coordinates but using a circular/rotational distance from origin?

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, rotations

Up front I apologize for my lack of familiarity with the relevant mathematical concepts, it’s been a long time since school.

I’m trying to build a draw bot similar to https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ArduinoFT/polar-drawing-machine-f7a05c?ref=search&ref_id=Polar&offset=0 where it naturally uses the polar coordinate system, but instead of using a linear axis, I want to use two rotating axes.

Something like this: [image: geometry]

So I was wondering if this was a kind of known coordinate system, where the rotation “a” of the larger circle is used instead of a radial distance from the origin of b, resulting in two rotations, that of the primary origin circle b, and the rotation of a (and a constant radius ratio) being the coordinates used to define a point.

Regardless of this being an existing concept, how would I go about translating from normal x,y coordinates into this new system?

Comment: Don't see why not, you essentially want to describe a point by the angles from two fixed points, correct?

Comment: What two coordinates are you using?  As long as they specify a point one should be able to translate between them and Cartesian coordinates.  You speak of a constant radius ratio, but I think you need something to specify the radius absolutely.  If we double the two radii we keep the ratio constant but double the distance of the point from the origin.